# two list to json in c#

Tags: arrays, json, list

I have three list in format below and I want to convert this to json format. length of list in all data sample are same.

```
List<string> data1=new List<string>{"col1","Col2","Col3",...}
List<string> data2=new List<string>{"a","b","c"...}
List<string> data3=new List<string>{"d","e","f"...}
```

I want to convert this data into json format where data1 is always to be key and other list to be value. I am expecting output something like

```
COnvertedSon = [{"col1":"a","col2":"b","col3":"c",....},
                {"col1":"d","col2":"e","col3":"f"....}]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
List<string> data1 = new List<string> {"col1", "Col2", "Col3"};
List<string> data2 = new List<string> {"a", "b", "c"};
List<string> data3 = new List<string> {"d", "e", "f"};


List<dynamic> list = new List<dynamic>(); 
var item1 = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
var item2 = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;

foreach (var item in data1)
{ 
    item1.Add(item, string.Empty);
    item2.Add(item, string.Empty);
}

var keys = item1.Keys.ToArray();
for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
{
    var key = keys[i];
    item1[key] = data2.ElementAt(i);
    item2[key] = data3.ElementAt(i);
}

list.Add(item1);
list.Add(item2);

var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list);
```

This doesn't include any error or null checking whatsoever and assumes that the lenghts of all Lists is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try by using the following code

```
 var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(list,
               Formatting.None,
               new JsonSerializerSettings()
               {
                   ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
               });
```